# Why does finite size scaling shift the critical temperature downward?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, scaling

The question is in the title.

Say we have a system where:
$$\xi \propto |T-T_c|^{-\nu}$$

In a finite system, $\xi$ cannot diverge and is limited by the size of the system. Thus:

$$
L =|T_\text{finite size transition}-T_c(\infty)|^{-\nu}
$$

You can easily enough solve this and find the shifted transition temperature. I don't find this argument compelling, though. $\xi$ diverges on both sides of the transition temperature, so there seems to be just as good of an argument that the temperature should shift *up*, not down, since that is where the correlation length first reaches the sample size.

Does anyone with a better understand of this than I care to enlighten me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the scaling relation only implies that the $T_\mathrm{max}(L) \ne T_c$.

Your question is answered by the calculations made in the seminal paper by [Ferdinand and Fisher (1969)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.185.832), who also provided (page 2) a physical argument:

> "[$T_\mathrm{max}(L) > T_c$] might be interpreted as an indication of increased cooperation between nearby spins as a result of extra "communication" via paths that encircle the torus. (By contrast, if boundaries in the shape of "free" edges are present we expect $T_\mathrm{max} < T_c$.)"

And they go on to mention that even for periodic boundary conditions (torus) one gets $T_\mathrm{max} < T_c$ for too high aspect ratios (about 3.139), a finite-size behavior that, at least at the time, was not yet understood.

Meta-comments:

- The question is old, but high among Google results, so worth answering.
- My knowledge in the field is recent and very limited: improvements and corrections are welcome.
- I was pointed in the right direction by the answer to this question: [Critical temperature and lattice size with the Wolff algorithm for 2d Ising model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200090/75633)