# What is finite size scaling theory?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, scaling

The question is in the title.

I read some articles about it but I could not understand it completely. What does it mean when we say *scaling* of any system?

Can you please give a brief introduction to this theory. An example or two will be very much appreciated.

A possible answer can be:

> [Critical temperature and lattice size with the Wolff algorithm for 2d Ising model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200090/critical-temperature-and-lattice-size-with-the-wolff-algorithm-for-2d-ising-mode/200184#200184)

Comment: Ir would help if you gave us an example of the type of system you are considering.

Comment: Actually right now, I don't have any system under consideration. I just want a general idea about this theory. Let's take the Ising model for discussion.

Comment: As a starting point, you may look at [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200184), although FSS is obviously more general than that.

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thank you so much. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I am glad it helped.